# Rails: How to check if an email is already enqueued

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job, rails-activejob

How to check that an email is already enqueued, Im using active job:

```
ofert_approved_notifier = Notifier.ofert_approved(@ofert.user, @ofert)
   if ofert_approved_notifier.deliver_later(wait: 1.hour)
      puts "Email ofert_approved sent successfully"
   else
      puts "Email ofert_approved could not be sent"
   end
```

As you can see above, Im sending an email to `@ofert.user` and it is delayed 1 hour before being sent, the above code is in a controller action, I want to check if the email is already enqueued for `@ofert.user`, I do not want to send the same email to the same user if it is already in the queue.

Is there a way I can check that?. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delayed::Job is an ActiveRecord object so you can check if a records exists.

```
Delayed::Job.where(...)
```

Look at the structure of stored records and find out how your email workers are stored and how to find them by email. Good luck!